# form gets submitted on choosing autocomplete option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, autocomplete

I have a form where I am taking two parameters from user and submitting form on press of Go button as well as on press of Enter key.
But in textbox when user types one char , textbox shows results for auto-complete.
And if user uses arrow keys to navigate through options and presses enter on a particular auto complete result, for gets submitted before selection of that selected option.
I want that user should be able to go down using arrow key, hit enter when he gets his option among the autocomplete list shown. and then if he presses enter , the form should be submitted

Here is the code in jsp

```
      <tr>  <td>param1: <input type="text" id="param1" placeholder="PARAM(Required)" onKeydown="Javascript: if (event.keyCode==13) getData();"></td>
          <td>Merchant ID: <input type="text" id="merchant" placeholder="Merchant ID(Optional)" onKeydown="Javascript: if (event.keyCode==13) getData();"></td>
    <td><button  class="btn" onclick="getData()" style="position:relative;">Go</button>

</td></tr></thead></table>
```

on press of enter key I am calling getdata function in JS which calls the servlet
How can I go about this?
Thanks

Comment: Can you post your tried out code. How did you submit the form when press the enter?

Answer (score 0):

If you can, please share with us more information about the code that you are using, the plugin or framework, etc...

So far with the poor information you share, you can disable the form submission if the enter hit is focussed on the input where the autocomplete goes. This is an example with jQuery

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" />
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
    $("#myInput").keypress(function(e) {
        var KeyCode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if(code == 13) return false; // 13 is the code for enter
    });
});
```

You can read more examples about event handling here: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Comment: But once the user selects one of the option out of autocomplete options I want the enter key to work, for form submission.